# Android Coroutines block UI click listener

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using MVVM as architecture, also the repository pattern. I have a Web service, a room database also. Using coroutines block any button I click.

There's a list/detail implemented with a fragment and an activity respectively.

I can figure out what's wrong in the way I implemented the coroutines and Viewmodel.

```
class BuySharedViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
private val repository: BuyRepository
var allBuys: LiveData<List<Buy>>


init {
    val buyDao = KunukRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).buyDao()
    val buyRemote = BuyRemote()
    repository = BuyRepository.getInstance(buyDao , buyRemote)
    //Use async because it return a result
    viewModelScope.launch { getAllBuys() }
    allBuys = buyDao.loadAllBuys()
}

private suspend fun getAllBuys() {
    repository.getBuys()

}
}
```

Here's is the Repository, it take data from web service and add it to the room database, while ViewModel get's data from room database.

```
class BuyRepository (private val buyDao: BuyDao, private val buyRemote: BuyRemote) {
private val job = SupervisorJob()
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)

companion object {
    //For singleton instantiation
    @Volatile private var instance: BuyRepository? = null

    fun getInstance(buyDao: BuyDao, buyRemote: BuyRemote) =
        instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: BuyRepository(buyDao, buyRemote)
                .also { instance = it}

        }
}


suspend fun getBuys(){
    refresh()
}

private suspend fun refresh(){

    try {
        val list = scope.async { buyRemote.loadBuys() }
        list.await().forEach { buy -> insert(buy) }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {}
}


@WorkerThread
private fun insert(buy: Buy) {
    buyDao.insertBuy(buy)
}


}
```

The fragment work, data are displayed, when i click on an item from that fragment(recyclerView) it work, the activity display details data. But none of the click on that activity works, like it doesn't detect the clicks. I guess it got something to do with the coroutines because when I comment out the code `viewmodelScope.launch { getAllBuys()}` from the BuySharedViewModel it works, because it load data from the previous call from room database, and the clicks works.

Here's the code in the detail view:

```
class BuyDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var sharedViewModel: BuySharedViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    lateinit var buy: Buy

    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BuySharedViewModel::class.java)

    val position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)
    sharedViewModel.allBuys.observe(this, Observer<List<Buy>> { buys ->
        buy = buys[position]
        val binding: com.example.drake.kunuk.databinding.ActivityBuyDetailBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, com.example.drake.kunuk.R.layout.activity_buy_detail)
        binding.buy = buy


        val agentNumber = buy.agentNumber?:"+50937438713"
        bnvContactAgent.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

            when (item.itemId) {
                com.example.drake.kunuk.R.id.action_call -> {
                    val callNumberUri = Uri.parse("tel:$agentNumber")
                    val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, callNumberUri)
                    startActivity(callIntent)
                }
                com.example.drake.kunuk.R.id.action_sms -> {
                    val smsNumberUri = Uri.parse("sms:$agentNumber")
                    val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, smsNumberUri)
                    startActivity(smsIntent)
                }
                com.example.drake.kunuk.R.id.action_email -> {
                    val uriText = "mailto:drakecolin@gmail.com" +
                            "?subject=" + Uri.encode("I'm interested in $agentNumber") +
                            "&body=" + Uri.encode("Hello, ")

                    val uri = Uri.parse(uriText)

                    val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                    sendIntent.data = uri
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email"))
                }
            }
            false
        }
```

This is the code of my fragment:

```
class BuyFragment : Fragment() {
companion object {
    fun newInstance() = BuyFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: BuySharedViewModel
private val buyList = ArrayList<Buy>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Get a new or existing ViewModel from the ViewModelProvider.
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BuySharedViewModel::class.java)

    // Add an observer on the LiveData returned by loadAllBuys.
    // The onChanged() method fires when the observed data changes and the activity is
    // in the foreground.
    viewModel.allBuys.observe(this, Observer<List<Buy>> { buys ->
        // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
        buys?.let { (rvBuy.adapter as BuyAdapter).setBuys(it) }
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    })
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy_fragment, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    rvBuy.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    rvBuy.adapter = BuyAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext,
        R.layout.buy_card, buyList)
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE


}
}
```

This is the code for the BuyDao:

```
@Dao
```

interface BuyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertBuy(vararg buys: Buy)

```
@Update
fun updateBuy(vararg buys: Buy)

@Delete
 fun deleteBuys(vararg buys: Buy)

@Query("SELECT * FROM buys")
fun loadAllBuys(): LiveData<List<Buy>>

@Query("DELETE FROM buys")
suspend fun deleteAll()

}
```

Comment: Where is your fragment code?

Comment: i ediTed. What do you thInk is The problem in ThERe

Comment: Could you also add code of your `buyDao`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewModelScope` by default uses `Dispatchers.Main` and it is blocking your UI.

Try this:

```
viewmodelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { getAllBuys()}
```

#### Edit:

The problem is your setting listner on BottomNavigation when your livedata is updated which is causing this weird issue.

Replace your `BuyDetailActivity` code with this:

```
class BuyDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var sharedViewModel: BuySharedViewModel
    private var agentNumber = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityBuyDetailBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_buy_detail)
        binding.buy = Buy()
        lateinit var buy: Buy

        sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BuySharedViewModel::class.java)

        val position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)
        sharedViewModel.allBuys.observe(this, Observer<List<Buy>> { buys ->
            buy = buys[position]
            binding.buy = buy
            binding.executePendingBindings()

            agentNumber = buy.agentNumber

            // set animation duration via code, but preferable in your layout files by using the animation_duration attribute
            expandableTextView.setAnimationDuration(750L)

            // set interpolators for both expanding and collapsing animations
            expandableTextView.setInterpolator(OvershootInterpolator())

            // or set them separately.
            expandableTextView.expandInterpolator = OvershootInterpolator()
            expandableTextView.collapseInterpolator = OvershootInterpolator()

            // toggle the ExpandableTextView
            buttonToggle.setOnClickListener {
                buttonToggle.setText(if (expandableTextView.isExpanded) com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.more else com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.less)
                expandableTextView.toggle()
            }

            // but, you can also do the checks yourself
            buttonToggle.setOnClickListener {
                if (expandableTextView.isExpanded) {
                    expandableTextView.collapse()
                    buttonToggle.setText(com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.more)
                } else {
                    expandableTextView.expand()
                    buttonToggle.setText(com.example.drake.kunuk.R.string.less)
                }
            }

            //Open photoView activity when clicked
            ivHouseDetail.setOnClickListener {
                applicationContext
                    .startActivity(
                        Intent(
                            applicationContext,
                            ViewPagerActivity::class.java
                        )
                            .putExtra("imageList", buy.propertyImage)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    )
            }
        })

        findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bnvContactAgent)?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.action_call -> {
                    Log.e("BIRJU", "Action call")
                    val callNumberUri = Uri.parse("tel:$agentNumber")
                    val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, callNumberUri)
                    startActivity(callIntent)
                }
                R.id.action_sms -> {
                    Log.e("BIRJU", "Action SMS")
                    val smsNumberUri = Uri.parse("sms:$agentNumber")
                    val smsIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, smsNumberUri)
                    startActivity(smsIntent)
                }
                R.id.action_email -> {
                    Log.e("BIRJU", "Action Email")
                    val uriText = "mailto:drakecolin@gmail.com" +
                            "?subject=" + Uri.encode("I'm interested in $agentNumber") +
                            "&body=" + Uri.encode("Hello, ")
                    val uri = Uri.parse(uriText)
                    val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                    sendIntent.data = uri
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email"))
                }
            }
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass Check now.

Comment: I get var allBuys: LiveData<List<Buy>> error: property must be initialize or must be abstract...

Comment: That's because the `allBuys` livedata won't be initialized immediately. check my answer. I updated it.

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass Please check my updated answer. I also pushed code to github so that you can check.

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass Don't forget to upvote and mark as correct if it solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks you so much, please add more explanation so I can avoid that in the future. Was it a bug or did i set something in the wrong way?

Comment: Your code was trying to set content view every time the data is changed in the livedata. Also, it was setting the navigation listener for the same condition. These thigs should only be done once and outside of such block, that is it should done in `onCreate` directly. That is the change that I have made in your code. @Dr4ketheb4dass